# Realtime database or Firestore for chat app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

We are currently working on a chat application which will also include post updates. One of the main features is the ability to chat one to one. Facebook like Posts can also be made that can be liked by some users.  I have been given two solutions, one with Real Time Database and one with Firestore. Which one is better suited towards a chat application and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, just to clarify, "Firebase" is an umbrella that contains a number of interconnected products, including cloud functions and two databases: 1. real-time database 2. and Firestore, as well as many other products.

If you want the most real-time solution, real-time database is probably the choice for you, because it has the lowest latency - it was designed with that priority.

Firebase has documentation about which database to choose  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore